# Convex Set- Intuition

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

I acknowledge that "Convex Set" has no hollow between any two points in the set as shown in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set).

But I guess this intuition is based only on the three dimensional space. What if more than four? How the hollow is defined?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector space. Then a set $D \subseteq X$ is called convex if

$$ \forall x,y \in D, \lambda \in [0,1]: (1-\lambda) x + \lambda y \in D ~~.$$

Intuitively this means that for any two points in the set, the line joining them is fully contained in $D$ as well.

I think this intuition works reasonbly well for more exotic spaces than $\mathbb{R}^3$. In any case, working with the definition is what gives the right answers.

Comment: How can we define "the line" more than 4 you said is my question. It's impossible to grasp its graphical intuition in an exotic space?

Comment: @Sato It's precisely what is written above: a line segment between two vectors $x,y \in X$ is given by the set $\{(1-\lambda) x + \lambda y \vert \lambda \in [0,1]\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sato You're welcome. If the answer is satisfactory, please do not forget to mark it as the accepted answer (by clicking the tick to the left of the question) such that the question does not appear in the "unanswered queue".

Answer (score 2):

Just to give some graphical intuition, here's a plot of the line segment given by $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y $ for two vectors $x$ and $y$:

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim(-2, 10)
plt.ylim(-2, 10)

x = np.array([1, 7])
y = np.array([8, 5])

for λ in np.linspace(0, 1, 20):
  s = λ*x + (1-λ)*y
  ax.quiver(s[0], s[1], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, width=0.003)
```